# Prevent Amazon ECS replaced 1 tasks due to an unhealthy status

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

My backend is running in AWS-Fargate. For me it's critical that it keeps running on some specific times as I have long running task (1.5 hours) without interruption.
This happened twice in the past week, AWS replaced a task due to an unhealthy status which broke the long running process. Looking at the health monitor I've noticed that the memory consumption was higher than usual, first time around 72% and second time 65%. The thing is - first time AWS replaced the task after 12 **days** of high consumption and second time after just 5 **minutes**.

1. Can this behavior be prevented and where do I find this setting? All information I've googled before was deployment related and not for runtime.
2. Does that happen because of the memory consumption? I can't find any additional info on the health status or some extended reason for replacement. Can I enable more logging somewhere to at least know more if that happens again?
3. If this behavior can't be prevented, can I specify some time ranges there the task must continue running and will be replaced later?

I'm a Backend developer and investigating the memory leak now. Having limited knowledge in DevOps I will appreciate if you point me into right direction or propose a workaround.
I've already created the alerts for high memory/cpu consumption.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have a load balancer that performs a health check, or have you configured a healthcheck command into the container? Do you have any logs that indicate what the container was doing at the time it was killed?

Comment: Also, have you considered running individual tasks for these long-running actions?

Comment: @kdgregory on the load balancer overview or specifically backend LB I don't see anything related to the health check. I see the health checks config on the target group page, added the screenshot to the question. The logs on the task itself showing just backend code logs but nothing about the task, in cloudwatch - same logs. Can I enable more logs for task itself?
Individual task is not really an option as the logic connects people for video calls and uses SignalR to inform Frontend about the call end and next call start so I have to quickly track their online + connection status in memory.

Comment: Yeah, target group health check. From your configuration, the target group fails to get a 200 response from the container within 5 seconds, and after 2 of these it marks the container unhealthy, at which point ECS kills it. You could try increasing both timeout and number of tries before a container is marked as unhealthy, _but this is just masking the actual problem._ If the health check can't get a response back from your server in 5 seconds, neither can your users.

Comment: @kdgregory thanks. Is that the only possible reason? My event was actually running normally so I can't really imagine no-response here. Is unusual memory consumption a possible reason? I mean, with 65% memory and <10% CPU I can't really imagine the simple /health to fail. I'm using a standard one from .NET
`builder.Services.AddHealthChecks();`
`app.MapHealthChecks("/health");`

Comment: An "unhealthy" status comes from health checks, either external (from the load balancer) or internal (defined in the container image or in the task definition). If it were me debugging this problem, I would first learn what health checks are enabled (so far we know about the LB, but maybe there's also an internal check), and then review logging (adding more logs if needed) to identify which is failing and why. For the LB health check, you can start by looking at the container's access log (which you might have to enable).

Comment: One other possibility is that you're using the Fargate Spot capacity provider. This is configured in the Service definition, and is a **really bad idea** for long-running tasks because AWS is free to terminate spot containers whenever it needs capacity.

Comment: @kdgregory don't think that I have that configured. From what I read it's rather a cheap solution for hosting dev or test environment, right? Anyway, is there a UI to check it? From what I read it can be configured using json only

Comment: You should be able to see this if you open the service in the Console.